# filter inputs not resize to column size, filter button not visible

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I have 7 columns and only the firstcolumn as you can see has the funnel button, the rest seem to be stuck behind the button to the right of it.
Is there something I was supposed to do to prevent that?

[image: I have multiple columns in this grid and only the first column has the filter button but the rest dont seem to show up]

```
<kendo-grid #grid [data]="gridView" [pageSize]="state.take" [skip]="state.skip" [sort]="state.sort" [filter]="state.filter"
          [scrollable]="'virtual'" [rowHeight]="35" [height]="450" [filterable]="true" [sortable]="true" (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)">
          <kendo-grid-column field="message" title="M" width="150">
            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
              <ng-template [ngIf]="dataItem.mT == 'W'">
                <i class="zmdi zmdi-alert-triangle zmdi-hc-fw zmdi-hc-lg c-amber pull-left"></i>
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template [ngIf]="dataItem.mT == 'E'">
                <i class="zmdi zmdi-alert-circle zmdi-hc-fw zmdi-hc-lg c-red pull-left"></i>
              </ng-template>
              <div>{{dataItem.m}}</div>
            </ng-template>
          </kendo-grid-column>
          <kendo-grid-column field="fn" title="F" width="100"></kendo-grid-column>
          <kendo-grid-column field="sn" title="S" width="75"></kendo-grid-column>
          <kendo-grid-column field="sac" title="Su" width="100"></kendo-grid-column>
          <kendo-grid-column field="o" title="DP" width="100"></kendo-grid-column>
          <kendo-grid-column field="pr" title="Date" width="125">
            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
              <div>{{formatDate(dataItem.pr)}}</div>
            </ng-template>
          </kendo-grid-column>
          <kendo-grid-column field="sfn" title="S" width="75"></kendo-grid-column> -->
        </kendo-grid>
```

Note: When investigate the individual inputs they are all the same size even though individual columns are different size

Comment: show us your HTML! show us your CSS! so we can help you :)

Comment: @HamedBaatour added html